# Using Demux to store data offchain in EOS blockchain

Tags: multi-index, data-storage

Does anyone have any idea dea how to use Demux with EOS Blockchain. There is  this [repo](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-project-demux-example)  where they give example how to use Demux.

I want to ask if there is any example for how to "use Demux without Docker"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've integrated it in my simple Chess Dapp if you'd like a code example:

https://github.com/NatPDeveloper/eos-chess/tree/master/js/lib/demux-js

Specifying contract:action to listen for:

```
const updaters = [
    {
      actionType: "chesschessch::setstat", // updated with current contract account name
      updater: updateMatchStatus,
    },
  ]
```

App.js setup to configure block indexing speed and API endpoint to ping:

```
// JUNGLE TESTNET
const actionReader = new NodeosActionReader(
    "https://poll.troonblockchain.io:9999", // Locally hosted node needed for reasonable indexing speed
    22238967, // First actions relevant to this dapp happens at this block
)

const actionHandler = new MyActionHandler(
    updaters,
    effects,
)

const actionWatcher = new BaseActionWatcher(
    actionReader,
    actionHandler,
    250, // Poll at twice the block interval for less latency
)

actionWatcher.watch() // Start watch loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Demux without docker. The best way is to take the example repository's "backend" folder and copy locally. Then you can modify the code to interface with a smart contract you write yourself and you can run it with nodemon. There are also examples in the main demux wiki that might be easier to follow than the larger / arguably needlessly complex demux example repo.

Comment: Are you using demux for your  usecase .?

Comment: @NirdeshKumarChoudhary Yes, I am currently building an application with Demux support and not using docker to do so. It seems complex at first, but at the end of the day Demux is really just a script that reads through blockchain history and makes notes in a database based on what it sees. The example project is heavily over-engineered but everything you need is in there in the 'backend' folder.